# How set default value for dynamic input ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to set default value for some input.

When i try in ionic framework to set a default value with

> ng-value

that work but when i submit the form, i ll never get the default value. I get undefined.
I think it's because i cannot initiate my objet before render my form.

But with dynamic input name i can't find the way.

This is my controler :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.frequences = [];
    $scope.medicaments = {
    15:{dose : 10,frequence :"matin", name:"test1"},
    16:{dose : 15,frequence :"matin", name:"test2"},
    17:{dose : 19,frequence :"matin", name:"test3"},
    };

    $scope.genererDate = function(form) {
            console.log($scope.frequences)
}
```

And my HTML

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="(key, value) in medicaments " >

<span class="">{{key}} - {{value.name}}</span>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="frequences[key]['dose']"  ng-init="frequences.key['dose'] = value.dose" >

    <input type="text" ng-model="frequences[key]['frequence']"  ng-init="frequences[key]['frequence'] = value.frequence">

</ion-item>
```

i have a Fiddle, ng-value doesn't work here, so i have try with ng-init.

http://jsfiddle.net/hwunpm5q/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{}` to define `$scope.frequences = {};` not an array `[]`

And it should be access through `frequences[key]['dose']` not `frequences.key['dose']`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.frequences = {};
   $scope.medicaments = {
    15:{dose : 10,frequence :"matin", name:"test1"},
    16:{dose : 15,frequence :"matin", name:"test2"},
    17:{dose : 19,frequence :"matin", name:"test3"},
    };
    
    $scope.genererDate = function(form) {
   console.log($scope.frequences)
     }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

 <form name="myform" novalidate="" ng-submit="genererDate(myForm)" > 
<ion-item ng-repeat="(key, value) in medicaments " >

<span class="">{{key}} - {{value.name}}</span>
          
<input type="text"  ng-model="frequences[key]['dose']"  ng-init="frequences[key]['dose'] = value.dose" >

<input type="text" ng-model="frequences[key]['frequence']"  ng-init="frequences[key]['frequence'] = value.frequence">

<br/>
</ion-item> 
<br/>

<button class="button button-full buttonValiderTraitement" type="submit" ng-click="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem, Happy to help :)